# how to create configurable associated products in magento using API?

Tags: php, api, magento, xml-rpc, magento-1.7

I am creating 2 configurable products and 10 simple products in `Magento` using API. I have assigned size and colors value in simple products and it's working fine. Now how do I assign specific attribute to configurable product? and same like that I want to assign simple product to configurable product. Does anyone know how we can add simple product to configurable product? I have already tried this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalog_product_link.assign.html

but it's not working to assign simple products to configurable product with attribute.
I know which tables contains configurable attribute.

```
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
```

I am able to modify existing API but I don't know which table contains configurable and simple products mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Tables used by All Products
-------------------------------------------------
catalog_product_entity                                                                change type_id to “simple”, “configurable” or “grouped”
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_website

Tables used by Simple Products
--------------------------------
cataloginventory_stock_item
cataloginventory_stock_status

Tables used by Configurable Products
---------------------------------
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
catalog_product_relation
catalog_product_super_link
catalog_product_link

Tables used by Grouped Products
------------------------------------
catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
catalog_product_link_attribute_int
catalog_product_link
catalog_product_relation
```